# How to find a common tree of two syntactic trees

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp

I want to find common nodes of two parse tree. Currently, I used Stanford parser and got two parse trees of two sentences. How can I find the common tree/nodes of these two sentence parse trees? I think if I can find the common tree, it will be easier to find the common nodes.

I want to post a capture of one paper, but I don't have enough reputation. If you need more clear explanation, I can send the capture later when I get enough reputation. Thanks!

Here is the link to the capture. In this capture, you can see the common nodes are in gray. My goal is to find these nodes and calculate the similarity between two trees. 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1g7zoGyaSAktDvH_q_Bz1mikkeQgS1v9M/view?usp=sharing

Comment: What you mean by common tree? Both tree have common subtree?

Comment: yes. two trees have common subtree

Answer (score 0):

can use subtree kernal approach to find the similarities of two trees